# Using Intel MKL to convert real time domain data to complex frequency and phase data and the inverse as well

Tags: c++, fft, intel-mkl

I'm writing an audio plugin and I would like to convert a series of real numbers representing sample values into a complex array representing frequency and phase. Then I want to be able to do the opposite, turning a complex array of frequency and phases to a series of real numbers, reconstructing the original data.

I'm using Intel MKL and I see only the possibility to perform real->real conversions or complex->complex conversions. Here's the reference I'm using: [Intel MKL FFT Functions](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-c/top/fourier-transform-functions/fft-functions.html#fft-functions).

In that reference, there are two overloaded functions: DftiComputeForward and DftiComputeBackward. So, I would like to use these to do the conversions. In the reference for `DftiCreateDescriptor`, the only options available for `DFTI_FORWARD_DOMAIN` are `DFTI_COMPLEX` and `DFTI_REAL`, but no option for mixed conversions.

*Edit*
I found that the phase is actually equal to `atan(imaginary/real)`. I don't want to mislead anyone getting information from questions.

*Edit*
I just learned that it's best to use `atan2(imaginary,real)`. More information is in the comments.

Comment: What is the problem? You can’t convert the real data to complex?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that actually and I'm not sure what that would mean. I did find that I might be able to input a complex array with the samples for the real numbers and 0's for the imaginary numbers and then for the inverse fft I might be able to just discard the imaginary numbers. I'm currently working on it.

Comment: Yes, that is the right approach.

Comment: For phase, use `atan2(imag,real)`. It computes `atan(imag/real)` but returns an angle in the full 2 pi range and also avoids issues with division by zero.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Just use `std::complex`. It has functions that deal with all that, by design.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica: As far as I know, MLK takes real and imaginary components separately. It would be inefficient to copy data just to use `std::complex::arg`. Which just calls `atan2` anyway. Besides, my comment was meant to instruct on the difference between `atan` and `atan2`, which are universal functions available in just about any language.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Gotcha. Makes sense. The `atan` vs `atan2` distinction is important. It's a bit sad that they don't teach `atan2` in grade school, generally. It's just a way nicer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every real number is a complex number: ℝ ⊂ ℤ. So going forward from `float` or `double` in time domain to `complex` is trivial. The language does that for you!

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    double d = 42.0;
    std::complex<double> z = d;
    std::cout << d << " = " << z << '\n';
}
```

Output: `42 = (42,0)`

And the C++ standard library also does everything else. It's quite simple, in fact. For once, the library does pretty much what it says on the box.

Even better: `std::complex` offers array access. You can reinterpret-cast `std::complex<T>` to `T[2]`, whether through a reference or a pointer. And thus, `std::complex` can be "stripped" of its identity and passed into any lower-level API that requires pairs of floats or pairs of doubles.

The complex frequency domain data can be converted to magnitude and phase, and back, as follows:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::complex<double> z{0.7071, 0.7071};
    double magnitude = abs(z);
    double phase = arg(z); // in radians

    std::cout << z << " ≈ (" << magnitude << "∠" << phase*180.0/M_PI << "°)\n";

    std::complex<double> z2 = std::polar(magnitude, phase);
    std::cout << " ≈ " << z2 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
(0.7071,0.7071) ≈ (0.99999∠45°)
 ≈ (0.7071,0.7071)
```

Once you get the "real" data back, it's not likely that the imaginary part of the time domain data will be zero - it depends on what processing you'll do with the frequency domain data. What you want to convert back is the magnitude of each complex time sample, using the `abs` function.

There's stuff in the C++ library that's mind-bogglingly overcomplicated, to the point where you have to have the reference open or you won't remember how to use it. See e.g. the mess known as the random number support. Ugh. But complex number support is relatively sane and even follows the notation used in teaching complex number arithmetic :)